# How to automatically move outlook emails to a file folder outside of outlook?

Tags: storage, archiving, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I have Outlook 2013.  Is there a rule or automatic way to move emails from outlook inbox or directories to a file folder on my computer or onto a server?  I tried archiving but it only creates a pst file and does not allow me to look at the individual emails afterwards.  Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Outlook VBA Email Autosave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811521/outlook-vba-email-autosave/24828160#24828160)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box. But it can be achieved using third-party product. As one of the developers, I can recommend [ReliefJet Essentials](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials). Its "Export Messages to EML Files" or "Export Outlook Items to MSG" utilities can be integrated with Outlook Rules and run automatically for each incoming email.

Comment: -1 for commercial solution.

Comment: At least it works. You can't get everything for free in this cruel world.

Comment: Agreed. In this instance, we have simple solutions that work just as well with zero cost.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution on StackOverflow where you can use Outlook VBA

[Outlook VBA Email Autosave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811521/outlook-vba-email-autosave/24828160#24828160)